# Strange bug while using import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange and HTTPserver in java

Tags: java, http, httphandler

I'm currently working on a "big" project, and I'm facing a incomprehensible bug. This one is just beyond my competence.
I will try to be as clear as possible, because there is a lot of code, I'll try to show you some screenshots of the debug intereface (breakpoint).

Basically, this is a program about surveys, admins can create surveys, users can answer them.. basic.

I'm doing it in java, using a HttpServer which creates a lot of contexts, (html pages) using the createContext method .

I'm also using a RMI object to manage the surveys and the results.

I have written a form for an admin to create a new survey, using the post method, i post it to another page so as to process the query.

Once I have done that, I have three variables to create a new survey : an id, a title, an array of questions, and an integer to say if the survey will be visible for the user or not. Note: I am 100% sure that those variables are correct

(Sorry for the french words in the code / screens, I'll try to rename most of them)

```
ISurveyManagement test = (ISurveyManagement)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/surveys");
```

I get my RMI object,

```
test.addSurvey(nsondage, titre, questions, 1);
```

Then I call my method to add the survey. (of course, all of those instruction are in the Handle method, from the interface HttpHandler)

This is what happens after the break point :

[image]

I have clicked on my button, the title has been correctly printed

[image]
Same thing for the RMI object, not null or anything, Then, we are supposed to go into the method of the RMI object:
[image]
But we are here!!! ServerImpl ExChange run?? what!! I pass a few steps
[image]
I passed all the step of the third picture, now we are again in the beggining of the Handle method?? why? and what about my call of addSurvey??
If I pass again a lot of steps, you will see that "HELLO", my title, and the RMI object will be printed again, then instead of going into my method it goes int that Thread-2 thing again and then crash...
[image]
[image]

I'm really sorry for this big ugly question, but I'm completly lost, I'm searching for hour ><

Thank you so much by advance if you can help me

EDIT:

this is the addSurvey method:

```
@Override
public void addSurvey(int n, String title, ArrayList<Question> q, int active) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("anything");
    this.loadSurveys();
    this.objSurveys.add(new Survey(n, title, q, active));
    this.saveSurveys();

}
```

The sysout at the begining is not displayed, I'm sure that the methods load and save work perfectly, I'm using them in an other functionnality.

EDIT2: as you asked, this is the code of the whole class test

```
public class CreationManagement implements HttpHandler {

@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

    String reponse = 
            "<html>"
              +"<head>"
               + "<title>Page admin</title>"
                +"<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/plain; charset=utf-8\"/>"
              +"</head>"
              +"<body style=\"font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;padding:20px;width:400px;border:1px solid #172183;\">"
                +"<p style=\"text-align:center;padding:5px;color:white;background:#172183;\">Vos changements ont bien été pris en compte!</p>"
                + "<form action=\"http://localhost:8080/admin.html\">"
                + "<button style=\"border: none;color: #ffffff;display: block;margin: auto;background: #172183;padding: 5px 20px;cursor:pointer;\">Retour</button>"
                + "</form>";

    URI requestedUri = t.getRequestURI();
    String query = requestedUri.getRawQuery();

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody(),"utf-8"));
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("Error flow" + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        query = br.readLine();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while reading line " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

   /*String [] p = query.split("&");
   for (int i = 0 ; i < p.length ; i++) {
       reponse += p[i] + "<br>";
   }*/
    ISurveyManagement test = null;
    try {
        test = (ISurveyManagement)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/sondages");
    } catch(NotBoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while getting rmi object : " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println("URL mal forme : " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch(RemoteException e) {
        System.err.println("not possible to get rmi obj : " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }   
    test.loadSurveys();
    int length = test.getSurveys().size();
    int nsurvey= length + 1;

    String[] op = query.split("&");
    String title = op[0].split("=")[1];   

    String[] params = Arrays.copyOfRange(op, 1, op.length);

   /*for (int a = 0 ; a < params.length ; a++) {
       System.out.println(a + " " +params[a]);
   }*/

    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
   //System.out.println("taille " + params.length );

    for (int i = 0 ; i < params.length ; i++) {
       if (i%5 == 0) {
           String[] detQ = params[i].split("=");
           int nq = Integer.parseInt(detQ[0].substring(1, detQ[0].length()));
           String libq = detQ[1];
           Question q = new Question(nq, libq, nsondage);
           q.setReponses(new ArrayList<Reponse>());
           questions.add(q);
       } else {
           String[] detR = params[i].split("=");   
           if (detR.length == 2) {
               String lib = detR[1];
               int q = Integer.parseInt(detR[0].split("_")[0]);
               int num = Integer.parseInt(detR[0].split("_")[1]);
               String l = "";
               if (num == 1) {
                   l = "A";
               } else if (num == 2) {
                   l = "B";
               } else if (num == 3) {
                   l = "C";
               } else if (num == 4) {
                   l = "D";
               }  
               Reponse r = new Reponse(l, lib, q, nsondage);
               questions.get(q-1).getReponses().add(r);
           }

       }
   }

    System.out.println("HELLO");
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(test);
   //Survey s = new Survey(nsurvey, title, questions, 1);
   test.addSurvey(nsurvey, title, questions, 1);
   //System.out.println(s.display());
   System.out.println(nsurvey);

    reponse += "</body></html>";

    try {
        Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
        h.set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("error while sending header : " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(reponse.getBytes());
        os.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("error sending corps : " + e);
    }

}

}
```

Is I said the survey is displayed correctly when I try to display it, the object is correctly created.

Comment: We need to see the exact test code and the addSurvey method. I would think your addSurvey method is fairly trivial, with an HTTP call which goes to your handle method, but since this is being executed twice, addSurvey is one of the possible locations of the bug.

Comment: @JeremyGurr as you asked I added the code, I don't really know but I'm afraid that addSurvey is not even called, as I said if i do a sysout in the begining of the method it does not appear, but if I do a sysout just before calling the method, it works. I'm losing my mind!!

Comment: That last chunk of code doesn't look like the client code that tests your handler, it looks like the actual code for the handler. Am I missing something? Are you just trying it out in a browser, and not using an automated test?

Comment: You're right, I'm trying it out in a browser, i'm a newbie, how could I use an automated test, as you say? I solved this problem by putting everything into a new Thread, I don't even know why it works, but I'm still very curious. What I did seems a bit "dirty" to me. If you have time, tell me about automated testing, because it's a real torture to debug this like I do ^^'